# Jupyter Notebook cannot open in Ubuntu WSL2

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La7RH.png)

I keep trying to use the jupyter notebook command and this error pops up. Could someone help?

Comment: did you installed it via anaconda??

Comment: please post the error message as text rather than image, it will help future users who searched the error message in search engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about it, you can just paste one of the displayed links in your browser and you'll be able to access it without issue.
The error only means powershell couldn't find the file that is used to automatically opens the notebook.